# After every Enqueue() all the values in the Queue become the same

Tags: c#, pointers, queue

I'm receiving some data over a socket and trying to add it to a  Queue so it can be dequeued by another thread that is much more slow, something like a buffer.

The problem is that everytime I enqueue a new value, all the values in the queue become that.

```
                    byte[] aux = new byte[1464];
                    aux = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;

                    //add the package to the package fifo list
                    lock (lockPktBuffer)
                    {
                        packetBuffer.Enqueue(aux);
                    }
```

First I thought that I was passing a pointer, so all the entries are just pointing to the same variable.

So I tried to do this:

```
                    lock (lockPktBuffer)
                    {
                        packetBuffer.Enqueue((byte[])ar.AsyncState);
                    }
```

But got the same problem.

Any ideia how to work this out ?

Comment: Your `AsyncState`s probably all refer to the same array.  You need to understand how objects & references work.

Comment: What is `ar`? Are you sure it's changing, and the value of `AsyncState`?

Comment: I know how objects and references work, just doesn't know how to do it on c# the "byte[] aux = new byte[1464];" wasn't suppose to create a new instance of the byte array ?

Comment: Show where you get ar from.

Comment: @DavidG `ar` is a `IAsyncResult`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what's going on (see the comments):

```
// This line creates a new array
byte[] aux = new byte[1464];
// This line "forgets" the new array, and replaces it with ar.AsyncState: 
aux = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;
```

As the result of this, all additions to the queue happen to enqueue the same object returned from `ar.AsyncState`, producing the effect that you see (all instances in the queue look the same).

Here is how you can fix it:

```
byte[] aux = ((byte[])(ar.AsyncState).ToArray();
...
packetBuffer.Enqueue(aux);
```

This call makes a copy of `ar.AsyncState` into a new array of bytes, making sure that all instances that you enqueue are independent

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Just help me to figure it out, when I did the `(byte[])(ar.AsyncState)` it acctually got a pointer to the AsyncState, so I have to explict covert it to array to get the data ?

Comment: @FvZ The cast (i.e. the `(byte[])` part) is sufficient to convert the object to an array. The `ToArray()` call makes a *copy* of the array, even when you already have an array. The array inside `ar.AsyncState` gets copied into a new array.

Comment: I got it, used to do the same on C. Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a reference. When you assign an array to another, it's the reference that is copied, it doesn't copy the data in the array.

To make a copy of the array you need to specifically copy the data inside it. Example:

```
// get the reference to the source array
byte[] source = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;
// create a new array with the same size
byte[] aux = new byte[source.Length];
// copy all the values from the source
Array.Copy(source, aux, source.Length);
```