# LinkedList addLast function replacing other values in list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, queue, keyvaluepair

I'm currently working on implementing a queue for sending out packets of data. however, I've run into an issue where when I use the addLast function on my LinkedList it replaces every Pair in the list with the Pair I'm adding to it.

The queue:

```
private LinkedList<Pair<Integer, ByteBuffer>> queue;
```

`Pair` has been imported from javafx.util.Pair;

Initialization of the queue:

```
queue = new LinkedList<>();
```

The method:

```
    public synchronized void addToQueue(int bytes, ByteBuffer data) {
        Pair<Integer, ByteBuffer> local = new Pair(bytes, data);
        queue.addLast(new Pair(bytes, data));

        if(bytes>2){
            int i = 0;
            for(Pair<Integer,ByteBuffer> datas:queue ){
                System.out.println("\n Data in the "+i+ "th position in queue is: ");
                printByteBufferAsBytes(datas.getValue(), datas.getKey());
                i++;
            }
        }

    }
```

In order to debug I've been printing  `data` whenever a data packet is sent. This method is also accessed to send smaller packets however it appears to work properly for smaller packets.

Upon running the code the following results are printed:

```
Data in the 0th position in queue is: 
1 5 40 -128 -58 0 0 42 111 34 -24 0 0 0 0 112 114 105 110 116 66 121 116 101 66 117 102 102 101 114 65 115 something was added to queue

 Data in the 0th position in queue is: 
2 5 40 -128 -58 17 0 115 -86 119 76 66 121 116 101 115 40 113 117 101 117 101 46 112 101 101 107 40 41 46 103 101 
 Data in the 1th position in queue is: 
2 5 40 -128 -58 17 0 115 -86 119 76 66 121 116 101 115 40 113 117 101 117 101 46 112 101 101 107 40 41 46 103 101 something was added to queue

 Data in the 0th position in queue is: 
2 5 40 -128 -58 38 0 -102 -46 -61 99 116 86 97 108 117 101 40 41 44 32 113 117 101 117 101 46 112 101 101 107 40 
 Data in the 1th position in queue is: 
2 5 40 -128 -58 38 0 -102 -46 -61 99 116 86 97 108 117 101 40 41 44 32 113 117 101 117 101 46 112 101 101 107 40 
 Data in the 2th position in queue is: 
2 5 40 -128 -58 38 0 -102 -46 -61 99 116 86 97 108 117 101 40 41 44 32 113 117 101 117 101 46 112 101 101 107 40 something was added to queue

 Data in the 0th position in queue is: 
3 5 40 -128 -58 59 0 109 60 120 12 11 41 46 103 101 116 75 101 121 40 41 41 101 117 101 46 112 101 101 107 40 
 Data in the 1th position in queue is: 
3 5 40 -128 -58 59 0 109 60 120 12 11 41 46 103 101 116 75 101 121 40 41 41 101 117 101 46 112 101 101 107 40 
 Data in the 2th position in queue is: 
3 5 40 -128 -58 59 0 109 60 120 12 11 41 46 103 101 116 75 101 121 40 41 41 101 117 101 46 112 101 101 107 40 
 Data in the 3th position in queue is: 
3 5 40 -128 -58 59 0 109 60 120 12 11 41 46 103 101 116 75 101 121 40 41 41 101 117 101 46 112 101 101 107 40
```

It appears that every time something is added to the queue all other values in the queue are set to the same value. 
If anyone knows the reason for this I would greatly appreciate any pointers.

Method printByteBufferAsBytes:

```
    public void printByteBufferAsBytes(ByteBuffer bytes, int bytesLength) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesLength; i++) {
            System.out.print(Byte.toString(bytes.get(i)) + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is that `Pair` class you are using? Is it a custom class you created yourself? Can you give the full qualifier name with package name of that `Pair` class.

Comment: can you share also the print method, please?

Comment: Pair is javafx.util.Pair, I'll add the print method right away

Comment: Are you using the same ByteBuffer and bytesLength when adding to the queue?
[Similar issue occurred here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873213/after-every-enqueue-all-the-values-in-the-queue-become-the-same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method `addToQueue` you need to copy the contents of updated ByteBuffer to some new byte array:

```java
    public synchronized void addToQueue(int bytes, ByteBuffer data) {
        byte[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(data.array(), bytes);

        Pair<Integer, ByteBuffer> local = new Pair<>(bytes, ByteBuffer.wrap(copy));
        queue.addLast(local);
    // ... the rest of the method remains as is

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of addLast() on LinkedList (in Java) is as follows:

```
 public void addLast(AnyType item)
   {
      if( head == null)
         addFirst(item);
      else
      {
         Node<AnyType> tmp = head;
         while(tmp.next != null) tmp = tmp.next;

         tmp.next = new Node<AnyType>(item, null);
      }
   }
```

There is an implementation of [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) in Java, I would recommend to use it instead of LinkedList. Also, dequeue and enqueue methods should be used to follow terminology.

enqueue() and dequeue() methods on Queue (in Java) are defined as follows:

```
public void enqueue(Item item) {
        Node oldlast = last;
        last = new Node();
        last.item = item;
        last.next = null;
        if (isEmpty()) first = last;
        else           oldlast.next = last;
        n++;
        assert check();
    }

public Item dequeue() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow");
        Item item = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        n--;
        if (isEmpty()) last = null;   // to avoid loitering
        assert check();
        return item;
    }
```

A small note on LinkedLists, method add() is equivalent to addLast().